# Database used for Parity

Tags: parity, database

Specific to Geth the database used is LevelDB. But what is the database used for parity?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm one of parity devs. We use [Rocksdb](http://rocksdb.org/). It's a key-value database developed by Facebook. We chose it mostly because of it's performance. In our benchmarks it was faster than LevelDB

From their webpage:

> RocksDB is optimized for fast, low latency storage such as flash drives and high-speed disk drives. RocksDB exploits the full potential of high read/write rates offered by flash or RAM.

Comment: Would you still use that database today?

Comment: @errata They are working on new ParityDB, which should replace it, so you can guess ;)
https://github.com/paritytech/parity-db

Answer (score 3):

The answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13643/794) is slightly out of date. Parity has [migrated](https://gitlab.parity.io/ddorgan/parity-ethereum/-/commit/458afcd2303539867e2e549ab0a5356415142b97) to use [blooms db](https://github.com/debris/blooms-db) which is an implementation of a [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to reduce overall disk reads.

The blooms are a db layer before the [kvdb](https://docs.rs/kvdb/0.1.0/kvdb/) RocksDB.