# For what data does Ethereum use Memory Database, and for what does it use Level Database

Tags: go-ethereum, memory, database, leveldb

Ethereum uses two databases Memory database and Level Database. Is data stored in MemoryDatabase different than LevelDb? In what cases is one database used over other?

The question is different from -[Which database(s) do the ethereum clients use and why?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/824/which-databases-do-the-ethereum-clients-use-and-why)
That question answers why LevelDb is used. This question is about how MemDB and LvlDb are different, why they are used, is the data stored in both databases different?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks It answers about use of LevelDb(and why it is used), My question is when is memoryDB used and does it store different data than LevelDb?

Comment: IMO that older question does replies part your title question (what database uses geth and how) since it is older so it may be not up to date. Perhaps you can edit the title asking about Memory database functionality, adding link to where it is used in geth source code.