# Basic Blockchain Implementation: how is the blockchain on a given node "synced" with that on another node?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, blocks

Here's my understanding of the execution flow of blockchain:

Consider two nodes, `node1` and `node2`. Let's say there are 10 users on `node1`. They're making `transactions`, but none of these are actually carried out since no `block` is mined.

When a `block` IS finally mined, these `unconfirmed transactions` are put into the `block` and executed - and the block is added to `node1's` blockchain. Then, through the `consensus protocol`, `node1's` `blockchain` in "synced" with `node2's blockchain` so that they both carry the same copy.

My question is: how does this "syncing" take place? Do you just supply `node2's blockchain` with the blocks it doesn't currently have? Or do you pass node1's blockchain by reference like this: `node_2_blockchain = node_1_blockchain`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each node synchronize **a copy** of the chain data with it's peers using a peer-to-peer mechanism. The protocol is defined by [the ÐΞVp2p Wire Protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EVp2p-Wire-Protocol) that indicates how data is shared between nodes. Blocks headers, block bodies, pending transactions are transferred separately (see for instance [how sync is done in Geth, the Go ethereum client](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/-/blob/eth/downloader/downloader.go#L463)). Some are encoded in the [RLP format](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP).

In the end, the whole block data is transferred in a serialized form to the peer node.
This is not a reference, otherwise we wouldn't have redundancy of the data in the network and if the original node fails, no one would have access to the data.

Each node have it's own local key/value database [which type depend on the choices of each client software](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/824/which-databases-do-the-ethereum-clients-use-and-why) to store the whole data.
Some of the non definitive or volatile data are only stored in memory databases or structures and written on disk only when fully settled.

Answer (score 1):

Block synchronization is carried out by Ethereum Wrie Protocol:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Wire-Protocol