# How an Ethereum Node stores data?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, parity

How an Ethereum client stores the blockchain data in the disk?

I know two of the major Ethereum clients is go-ethereum and parity, so I'm also asking if they store data in a different way or if there are some common threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not mandatory that clients store the same data or use the same storage implementation.

For example geth uses LevelDB and parity uses RocksDB as storage backend.

Ref: [Which database(s) do the ethereum clients use and why?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/824/which-databases-do-the-ethereum-clients-use-and-why)